# Progress bar: how to make color transition according to the progress?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been looking around for a D3 JS progress bar and this is the best match I have found: 
https://bl.ocks.org/sarahob/1e291c95c4169ddabb77bbd10b6a7ef7

However, this is an ordinal domain with three states and hardly reusable for a real life application. I'd like to change it in a way that no matter to what arbitrary percent I increase it to; the color between say yellow to green will proportionally change to the new progress/height. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3 has a bunch of very useful color methods (which you can [see here](https://github.com/d3/d3-color)) and color schemes (which you can [see here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic)).

However, what you're asking can be achieved with a simple linear scale, like this (D3 v3, as in your example):

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(['yellow', 'limegreen']);
```

As we didn't set the domain it will be `[0, 1]` by default, which is handy because our progress goes from 0% to 100%.

You can also use three colours, setting the domain accordingly:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
    .range(['yellow', 'orange', 'limegreen']);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('width', 500);

var segmentWidth = 300;

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
  .range(['yellow', 'orange', 'limegreen']);

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bg-rect')
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .attr('ry', 10)
  .attr('fill', 'gray')
  .attr('height', 15)
  .attr('width', segmentWidth)
  .attr('x', 0);

var progress = svg.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'progress-rect')
  .attr('fill', colorScale(0))
  .attr('height', 15)
  .attr('width', 0)
  .attr('rx', 10)
  .attr('ry', 10)
  .attr('x', 0);

progress.transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .attr('width', segmentWidth)
  .attrTween("fill", function() {
    return function(t) {
      return colorScale(t)
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What changes I need for v4? e.g. `d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 0.5, 1]).range(['yellow', 'orange', 'limegreen'])` instead of `d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 0.5, 1]).range(['yellow', 'orange', 'limegreen'])` and what else?

Comment: Nothing else, it's pretty much that.

Comment: It doesn't show for me :((( where are the classes `bg-rect` and `progress-rect` defined?

Comment: The classes make no difference (I'm just copying the bl.ocks you shared). You must have another issue, not related to the scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two overlapping elements instead of one, the one at the back in yellow and the one at the front in green with an increasing `opacity`.

Or even better, you can set the color in [`hls`](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) instead of [`rgb`](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp) and change the `hue` and `lightness` components as the progress increases or decreases:

```js
const progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
const range = document.getElementById('slider');

const hueStart = 60;
const hueEnd = 120;
const hueRange = hueEnd - hueStart;
const lStart = 50;
const lEnd = 32;
const lRange = lEnd - lStart;

range.oninput = () => {
  const percent = range.value;
  const alpha = percent / 100;
  const hue = hueStart + hueRange * alpha;
  const lightness = lStart + lRange * alpha;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    progressBar.style.width = `${ percent }%`;
    progressBar.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${ hue }, 100%, ${ lightness }%)`;
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.progressBar__base {
  position: relative;
  height: 32px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 32px;
}

.progressBar__progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar__base">
  <div class="progressBar__progress" id="progressBar"></div>
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="slider">
```